# Can I rely on SoundEffects being stopped when unloaded?

Tags: xna-4.0, sound, documentation

I am using XNA's `SoundEffect` class to play sounds. I have to `unload` all sounds from the corresponding `ContentManager` for technical reasons, while some of them are still playing.

What happens to sounds that are still playing (via `SoundEffect` instances) when being `unload`ed? It seems that they just stop abruptly. Is this a deterministic behaviour I can rely on? Can it cause any errors when `unloading` sounds that are currently playing?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't do things correctly and stop playing all sounds first? What are the "technical reasons"?

Comment: Some sounds I need to play using the Play() method that plays the sound (afaik) creating an instance that I cannot access. Without that instance, I cannot stop the sound once it has been started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Unload()` on the `ContentManager` it will internally call `Dispose()` on any object that was loaded that implements the `IDisposable` interface (which `SoundEffect` does). Therefore yes, it is deterministic that calling `Unload()` on the `ContentManager` will stop all `SoundEffect` instances as they are being disposed.

Shawn Hargreaves wrote a nice [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/09/contentmanager-readasset.aspx) about the `ContentManager` that details the extensibility points of `ContentManager` while also describing this default behavior.